# Silverlight Optimization

Tags: silverlight, optimization

I have an application written in Silverlight 5, which requires optimization.
Application contains a TreeView, each element of the tree contains about 25 editbox controls with background image. The tree has an average of about 50 elements, which makes ~ 1250 edit controls. The problem is that it scrolls the tree or select editboxs very very slowly, even if only 5-6 elements are visible.
I think virtualization in this case will not help because the problem is in the drawing of visible elements.

Does anyone have any idea how to optimize?

Can't post image becouse of my low score but one TreeView Item looks like:

> Floor 4 (0xAA03) |EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB|EB (25)

where EB is EditBox in form of rectangle with image background and text for room number. Editboxs are created dynamic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us some code? Perhaps an essential abstract so we don't have to read the whole declaration.

Comment: Sorry, can't paste code. Its property and i'm not the owner.

Comment: Each treeview item contain some text following with ~25 editbox controls into 1 grid row (25 columns). The treeview is about 1/2 of the screen.

Comment: Ok, curios but I can understand that. What concrete controls did you use? What's the intention of the view? Can you show us at least the composition of one item?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's difficult to give a qualified answer. But let's have a try. I think your statement virtualization won't help is not fully true, but it doesn't seem to be the main problem.

An educated guess is, that you're using DropShadows or OpacityMasks which are a real performance killer. If it's like that please remove them and tell me the result. Otherwise I'm running out of ideas, sorry.